# Path of an electron in magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrons, path-integral

Can we describe the path of an electron (or any subatomic particle) inside, say magnetic field?

We generally described in terms of classical laws that this path will be spiral or circular.

But path-integral formulation says that a particle can go from a point **A** to **B** in **infinitely many possible paths** and we have to consider the contribution from all.

So how we describe the path of subatomic particle inside linear accelerator or cyclotron?

Comment: I assume you are confused with the fact that if something goes from a to b from all possible paths how an electron goes from a to b while being confined in an cylotron. you have to think the electrons as a wave packets which have a gaussian profiles in both  position and momentum space.

Comment: You might be interested in learning about [particle-in-cell simulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-in-cell).

Answer (score 1):

> But path-integral formulation says that a particle can go from a point A to B in infinitely many possible paths and we have to consider the contribution from all.

Sure, but it also says there's a probability distribution that you have to apply to those paths. And when you do that, you end up with a strongly favored path that often looks classical. This is sort of the **whole idea**.

The result is often so close to classical that one finds the physics of fusion reactors dominated by semi-classical approaches. Perfectly good treatments of plasma diffusion model it as the collision between particles moving on purely classical paths.